# Javascript if/else Weather always goes into else

Tags: javascript

I am getting weather data from an API and want to display icons.

It looks like this: (for testing I am now not using the api data)

```js
var icon = "clear-night";

if (icon == "clear-day") {
  icon = "day-sunny";
}
if (icon == "clear-night") {
  icon = "night-clear";
}
if (icon == "rain") {
  icon = "raindrops";
} else {
  icon = "thermometer";
}
console.log(icon);
```

If I delete the "else" part, it prints out "clear-night" - but if i have the "else" it prints out "thermometer".
This is totally basic, but I just can't figure it out...
Thank you!

Comment: put an `else` in front of all your `if` except the first one. Or look into the switch/case construct.

Comment: You execute 3 `if` statements. All 3, unconditioned.

Comment: use `else if` instead of `if` ( second if onwards )

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `else if(icon != 'night-clear')` but `switch` it better in this case

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're basically ignoring any previous value you considered for `icon`.

In your case you consider whether `icon`'s value is `"clear-day"` or `"clear-night"`, then you check whether it is `"rain"`. If it's not `"rain"` the `else` clause of only that `if` gets executed.

You need to use `else if`s if the conditions are mutually exclusive.

```
var icon = "clear-night";

if (icon == "clear-day") {
    icon = "day-sunny";
}
else if (icon == "clear-night") {
    icon = "night-clear";
}
else if (icon == "rain") {
    icon = "raindrops";
} else {
    icon = "thermometer";
}

console.log(icon);
```

Even better, as others suggested in the comments, use a `switch` construct.

```
var icon = "clear-night";

switch(icon) {
case "clear-day":
    icon = "day-sunny";
    break;
case "clear-night":
    icon = "night-clear";
    break;
case "rain":
    icon = "raindrops";
    break;
default:
    icon = "thermometer";
}
console.log(icon);
```

Comment: Thank you! I now used the switch statement, works perfectly fine :)

Comment: Looking at your history you never seem to have accepted an answer. But it's never too late to start :) Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) out.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see constructs like this, I start thinking if a simple map would be an ideal solution.

Below is an example.

```js
function daymap(icon) { 
  return {
    "clear-day": "day-sunny",
    "clear-night": "night-clear",
    "rain": "raindrops" 
  }[icon] || "thermometer";
}

console.log(daymap("clear-night"));
console.log(daymap("rain"));
console.log(daymap("other"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about that but seems like a great solution. I now used the switch statement.